# Getting random arrays not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple JS that will get random arrays and post them via div container. Here's what I have so far, now keep in mind I'm horrible with JS.

```
function timedMsg() {
    currMsg++;
    document.getElementById('timedMsgDiv').innerHTML = msgArr[currMsg % msgArr.length];
};

function init() {
    currMsg = -1;
    msgArr = Array('Computer.', 'Uploading', 'Random');
    timedMsg();
    var t = setInterval("timedMsg()", 50);
};

window.onload = init();
```

It only gets 'Computer' and then does not flip through them randomly or loop or anything. Any reason why? Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R8SYf/

Comment: `window.onload = init;`

Comment: Some things don't look right, in your code and fiddle. Fixed http://jsfiddle.net/R8SYf/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the function name to `setInterval()`, like this:

```
var t = setInterval(timedMsg, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R8SYf/6/

Comment: `setInterval(timedMsg, 2000);`

Comment: @elclanrs - Yeah, that's shorter and nice!

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Will set answer once I'm able to.

Comment: But this is not the real issue though. The real problem is how the fiddle is set up, OP has to load scripts in head `No wrap - <head>`, and assign a function to the load event (not the returned value) and it should work http://jsfiddle.net/R8SYf/13/

Comment: @elclanrs what do you mean?

Comment: This is good practice but you have other problems in the code. This is your code and fiddle fixed, just go line by line you'll see the difference. http://jsfiddle.net/R8SYf/11/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your code:

1) When you pass a string to `setInterval` you trigger `eval` and your function is run in the global context, you don't want this. To fix it simply pass a reference to the function; rebember functions are objects too:

```
var t = setInterval(timedMsg, 2000);
```

2) The `window.load` event expects a function but you're assigning the returned value of the `init` function which is `undefined`. Like in the case above you need to pass a function object, not execute the function:

```
window.onload = init;
```

3) Your fiddle is set-up to load the code in the `onLoad` event, but you're assigning your own function. You need to change the behavior to `No wrap - in <head>`.

4) Although is works, using the Array constructor to create arrays is not good practice. Simply use the literal syntax:

```
msgArr = ['Computer.', 'Uploading', 'Random'];
```

Fixed http://jsfiddle.net/R8SYf/11/

Comment: How could I get this randomized? By the way, I'll be adding a lot more.

Comment: Shuffle your array first, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: I understood a little bit, but would not know how to modify it to work inside my script.